# Python-Hex editing specific locations in a file

Tags: python

I want to open up about 135 different offsets in the file in hex form. The sections of interest are the names of the characters skins in the game, so an easy way to edit these and save them would save me MEGA time.

This is code I ended up with, something I could understand. I converted the file to HEX and TEXT form:

```
import binascii
filename = 'Skin1.pack'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
out = binascii.hexlify(content)

f = open('hex.txt', 'wb')
f.write(out)
f.close()

import binascii
filename = 'hex.txt'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()

asci = binascii.unhexlify(content) 
w = open('printed-hex.txt', 'wb')
w.write(asci)
w.close()
```

Now im trying to use this byte to replace some of the text in the file

```
f = open("printed-hex.txt",'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

newdata = filedata.replace("K n i g h t       ",input)

f = open("printed-hex.txt",'w')
f.write(newdata)
f.close()
```

but I'm met with this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dee\Desktop\ARC to HEX\Edit-Printed-HEX.py", line 3, in <module>
    filedata = f.read()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2656: character maps to                                 <undefined>
```

Comment: 1) Do you insist on opening the fragments in an external editor or editing from python's console like it's shown in the code is ok? 2) how do you find the fragments of interest? I.e., can this be automated?

Comment: 1) i dont know anything about HEX editing with python. 2)i dont insist on open anything in any manner im just trying to figure out how to do what ive stated.

Comment: "So, the idea is to open up about 45 different places in the file in hex form. For each selection, i want to edit is anywhere from 1 to 3 lines in the hex editor.(witch im assuming is a fragment the lines im reffering to)"

Comment: SO all im trying to do is open 45 "locations" (some do contain more than one or two "fragments". and convert the HEX format to text for editing back to HEX form, and finally saved back to the file.

Comment: The downvote was probably because you ask a question about programming in a language without even bothering to learn its basics. This site is not a tutorial collection, it's Q&A.

Comment: Well sorry then, if you dont have something to contribute to this i suggest you go patronize someone else for trying to learn. BTW i googled python coding help and this site came up.

Comment: as i CLEARLY stated im learning python, i know the basics. i have never HEX edited with python. or any other coding language for that matter. So dont expect someone to just know the information from nowhere.i figured some nice coder that knows more than i do could give me a few pointers, but it seem 99% of coders out there will just chastises you for not knowing the information already.

Comment: Like all the down votes ive gotten already prooves that.

Comment: "if you could just go into detail about what each line does" hardly qualifies as that, this all can be learned from docs. All in all, this doesn't mean you won't get any answers. This means you'll probably gets answers that you'll also need to learn some basics to put to use.

Comment: I know the Basics, ive said that.. by "lines" i mean the offset. i figured that would be clear if youve ever used a hex editor before.

Comment: im trying to , open about 135 offsets convert to text form. edit them, convert back to HEX form and save to the file.

Comment: and this code isnt applyed to anything relevent to me so i dont know what its doing.

Comment: i Mean even the first line. $ xxd data <- not assign to any kind of variable, not clearly indicating where its attached. is xxd some type of file or module? i have no clue.

Comment: @Death_Dealer xxd is not python, it is an external command for doing a hex dump of a file. It comes with the vim text editor.

Comment: [This](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) might give some insight into the downvotes

Comment: i dont care for your insults @chthonicdaemon, i got the help i needed. and he was more than happy to help me understand what i was trying to ask.

Comment: There was no insult either explicit or implicit in a link explaining how to ask questions that will lead to good answers.

Comment: i assumed it was some kind of insult because the title reads "How To Ask Questions The Smart Way" in some way implying im stupid or incapable of learning.

Comment: I posted that link because of the conversation at the top of this thread where people pointed out that you haven't used this forum correctly and you accused them of being patronising and chastising you for wanting to learn. SO works best when there is a clear question with a clear answer. It's not really a good place for back-and-forth conversation. Your question seems quite close to the "chatty" questions mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), which is probably why it was voted down. Adopting the culture here will help you to get more out of SO. Good luck!

Comment: It's usually a good idea to ask a new question rather than to keep morphing one question.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon this is the last time i will say this, im new here.  i dont know how things work yet. having you tell me this information in this question is just filling it up with more "chatty"ness thereby making you a hypocrite of your own rules and regulations. this is why i said people here just like to chastise instead of actually helping. if you really want to help people understand how to get a clear answers here try keeping it short and to the point. and in only one comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To nitpick, hex doesn't have 'lines' so you might want to think about how you will limit the location you want to edit. Perhaps edit a fixed number of bytes.

The output you have seen in the console is python attempting to print binary data. It has printed the extended characters because there arn't printable characters that correspond to the characters in the string. You can see that some characters are printable, and that is why you have things like `7(5.` in it.

What you need is an easy way to represent the binary data as hex, and a way to convert back. I'll leave the implementation of the actual editor up to you.

```
import mmap

handle = open('/usr/bin/xxd', 'r')
memorymap = mmap.mmap(handle.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)

value_to_hex = dict(enumerate('0123456789ABCDEF'))
hex_to_value = {v: k for (k, v) in value_to_hex.items()}


def expand_byte(byte):
    """ Converts a single byte into 2 4 bit values """
    return [(byte >> s) & 0xF for s in [4, 0]]


def compact_bytes(values):
    """ Converts 2 4 bit values into a single byte """
    return (values[0] << 4) | values[1]


def bin_to_hex(data):
    """ Converts binary data to hex characters """
    return [value_to_hex[v] for b in data for v in expand_byte(b)]


def hex_to_bin(hexadecimal):
    """ Converts hex characters to binary data """
    return [
        compact_bytes([hex_to_value[v] for v in hexadecimal[i:i + 2]])
        for i in range(0, len(hexadecimal), 2)
    ]

test_data = [ord(c) for c in memorymap[0:8]]
hex_data = bin_to_hex(test_data)
final_data = hex_to_bin(hex_data)

print "From '{0}'\nto '{1}'\nto '{2}'".format([chr(c) for c in test_data], hex_data, [chr(c) for c in final_data])
```

This prints:

```
From '['\x7f', 'E', 'L', 'F', '\x02', '\x01', '\x01', '\x00']'
to '['7', 'F', '4', '5', '4', 'C', '4', '6', '0', '2', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0']'
to '['\x7f', 'E', 'L', 'F', '\x02', '\x01', '\x01', '\x00']'
```

Bitwise value manipulation is something you may not have come across before, so you should learn about it. The `>>` `<<` `|` and `&` operators are [bitwise operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Comment: So this example was a little over my head with all the different syntax, so i ended up trying this.

Comment: so i posted the code i ended up using, is there anything you can tell me about why i might be getting that error? i would have used the method you mentioned i just couldn't get it to work properly. im pretty new to python and coding in general.

Comment: when i run your code its says                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dee\Desktop\ARC to HEX\.PCK to HEX.py", line 3, in <module>
    handle = open('/usr/bin/xxd', 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/xxd'
>>>

Comment: Hey I selected the file /usr/bin/xxd because I thought you had it (based on having used it in your example). It is really just an arbitrary binary file. You would want to change that anyway to whatever file you were going to edit.

Comment: As far as the syntax goes the code uses the following data types: dictionaries and lists. The following constructs are used: list comprehensions, dictionary comprehensions, bitwise operations. The functions are enumerate, ord, and chr. If you google for each of these with python then you should be able to find documentation. Obviously this comment is much too short to explain them all!

Comment: You have changed your question so much that it really deserves a second question. I would point out that you don't need to import the same package multiple times, and that you appear to be performing the hex to binary transformation on a variable that does not contain hex (you create hex and assign it to `out` but attempt to reverse the content stored in `content`).

Comment: Yes i realized thatXD i said im new to python, i probly should have said expect errors in my codeXD i got the xxd binary and got it working with some code. ill see what i cant do with it today.

Comment: Ok so with the "def compact_bytes(values):"  Can i use this to convert a 4 byte hex string to a 2 byte hex string? like                (b '\x00\x00\x00\x11' ) to (b '\x00\x11' )?

Comment: That is not really the intent of that code, so I would not recommend it. As it happens it would produce that output but that is by coincidence. It is likely that you are looking at UTF text (probably as UTF-16), and so you should do a proper character set conversion to transform it to ASCII.

Comment: your saying convert it using binascii? to shorten the character set?

Comment: @Mathew Fraglen im actually trying to write the file size of a text string to a file and the files size is held in a 2 byte form (b '\x00\x11' ) being ''17'' characters long. when i write the size to the file im getitng the 4 bytes  (b '\x00\x00\x00\x11' ). i dont think using binascii will work because the values are not written in ascii there in hex form in the file, and using "def compact_bytes(values):" only seems to shorten it to three bytes long.

Comment: I didn't really understand why you would want to compress those hex values together like that, so I thought you were trying to perform a character encoding conversion. Now that you have explained the problem I can help a bit more :) Fundamentally yes if you have the stringified hex you can convert it back into binary in that way. Remember that when you have sequences like \x00 what you have is _binary_ data not _hex_ data. If you convert _binary_ data to _binary_ again you will run into problems.

Comment: Dealing with this subject properly is probably worth another question rather than a stream of comments!

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the data, operate the [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html?highlight=mmap#module-mmap) object like in the example code;

If you want to open a fragment of data in a hex editor, copy it into a [temporary file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html?highlight=tempfile#module-tempfile), then open the file in the editor e.g. with [`subprocess.check_call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.check_call), then copy the new file's contents back. (That's unless your editor has a command-line option that allows to set focus at a specific offset at startup)

To use just Python's console, use something like

```
" ".join("%02x"%ord(c) for c in <data>)
```

to see the data in hex (or just `repr` to see it in ASCII), or, for more `xxd`-like look and feel, something 3rd-party like [`hexview`](https://github.com/rgbkrk/hexview).