# Edit .txt file in Hexadecimal values

Tags: python-3.x

I want to edit a .txt file in hexadecimal values, so far I have not found anything besides this:
[Python-Hex editing specific locations in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509916/python-hex-editing-specific-locations-in-a-file)
But I don't understand a thing there must be an easier way then the solution posted there?
Also, I want to be able to replace specific hex values with different hex values.
More specifically I want to change all '85' hex values to 'A5'

I just started learning this and so far I have been able to make a "Hello World" and a console Calculator.
So Total Newbie at this, don't expect me to understand much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the text file in binary mode and use the `bytes.replace` method for replacements:

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f, open('file_new.txt', 'wb') as o:
    o.write(f.read().replace(b'\x85', b'\xA5'))
```

Comment: Thanks man, although I had to change to uppercase A5 otherwise it wouldn't work. ;)

Comment: Well thanks again. Just checked that mark aswell. First time on this site also, pretty obvious right?